# Converting text to datetime.datetime object? (Error: ValueError: time data '2022-04-18T10:00:00-07:00' does not match format '%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')

Tags: python, datetime, utc, python-datetime, strptime

I have a datetime.datetime object that gets stored as text in a text file. Later, I have to convert that text back to a datetime.datetime object. The object is in this format `2022-04-18T10:00:00-07:00` but I'm having trouble using the strp time function to convert the text back. I tried running `date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(timedatestamp, '%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')` but that format doesn't work because the time data is formatted wrong. Any clue as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's `%Y` for a four-digit year, not %y. Or use datetime 's `fromisoformat`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)